# Inner join will not use index

Tags: mysql

Why would this query (and a number of similar variants) not use the index for ASIN on the 'tags' table? It insists on a full-table scan even when A contains just a few rows. As 'tags' table on production contains nearly a million entries, it's killing the query rather badly.

```
SELECT C.tag, count(C.tag) AS total
FROM
(
    SELECT B.*
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ASIN FROM requests WHERE user_id=9
    ) A
    INNER JOIN tags B USING(ASIN)
) C
GROUP BY C.tag ORDER BY total DESC
```

EXPLAIN shows no index being used (run on test DB so rows in 'tags' is low, but still a full table scan):

```
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>         | system | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL |    0 | const row not found            |
|  2 | DERIVED     | <derived3>         | ALL    | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL |   28 |                                |
|  2 | DERIVED     | B                  | ALL    | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL | 2593 | Using where; Using join buffer |
|  3 | DERIVED     | borrowing_requests | ref    | idx_user_id   | idx_user_id | 5       |      |   27 | Using where
```

Indexes:

```
| book_tags |          1 | asin           |            1 | ASIN        | A         |         432 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| book_tags |          1 | idx_tag        |            1 | tag         | A         |        1296 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| book_tags |          1 | idx_updated_on |            1 | updated_on  | A         |         518 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE
```

The query was rewritten from an INNER JOIN which was having the same problem:

```
SELECT tag, count(tag) AS total 
FROM tags 
INNER JOIN requests ON requests.ASIN=tags.ASIN 
WHERE user_id=9 
GROUP BY tag 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

EXPLAIN:

```
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tags          | ALL  | NULL                 | NULL     | NULL    | NULL | 2593 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | requests | ref  | idx_ASIN,idx_user_id | idx_ASIN | 33      | func |    3 | Using where
```

I get the idea this is a real basic point I'm missing, but about 4 hours work on it has got me nowhere. Any advice is welcome.

EDIT:

I can see that the first query using sub-queries won't use indexes thanks to some replies, but this was being used as it ran twice as quick as the bottom query with just the INNER JOIN.

As an example, there are 70k rows in requests (all with an indexed ASIN), and 700k rows in tags, with 95k different ASINs in tags, each with less than 10 different tag records.

If a user has 10 requests, I only want the tags from those 10 ASINs to be listed and counted. In my mind, this should use tags.idx_ASIN and should lookup 100 rows (10 ASINs, each with max of 10 tags) at most from the tags table.

I'm missing something...I just can't see what.

EDIT:

requests CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `requests` (
  `bid` int(40) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ASIN` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','inactive','pending','deleted','completed') COLLATE     utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `added_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status_changed_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_emailed` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`bid`),
  KEY `idx_ASIN` (`ASIN`),
  KEY `idx_status` (`status`),
  KEY `idx_added_on` (`added_on`),
  KEY `idx_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `idx_status_changed_on` (`status_changed_on`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=149380 ;
```

tags CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags` (
  `ASIN` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `updated_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  KEY `idx_tag` (`tag`),
  KEY `idx_updated_on` (`updated_on`),
  KEY `idx_asin` (`ASIN`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

There is no primary key on tags. I don't usually have tables without primary keys, but didn't see the need on this one. Could this be an issue?

AHA! Different charsets and collations. I shall correct that and try again!

Later:

That got it. Query went down from 10secs to 0.006secs. Thanks to everyone for getting me to look at this differently.

Comment: probably because of the inner select - the index will not apply on the subquery

Comment: The original query at the bottom does not have a subquery, but still performs a full-table scan.

Comment: It could be that MySQL doesn't consider the expense to reorder worth the savings afforded from using an index. Try removing the `order by` and/or `group by` to see if this causes MySQL to use your index.

Comment: Removed ORDER BY and GROUP BY from the bottom query (not the one with sub-queries) but still get a full-table scan

Comment: Can you show your create table for requests?

Comment: That helped me to see the tables used different charsets, so I guess mySQL viewed the ASIN fields as not being comparable. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out ^_^ Go ahead and write an answer and accept it since you were able to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AHA! Different charsets and collations. I shall correct that and try again!

Later:

That got it. Query went down from 10secs to 0.006secs. Thanks to everyone for getting me to look at this differently.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't index subqueries. If you want indexes to improve performance of your queries, rewrite them to not use subqueries.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't aware of subqueries not being indexed, but still don't get why the second query still performs a full-table scan.

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the order of the tables in your original query:

```
SELECT tag, count(tag) AS total 
FROM requests 
INNER JOIN tags ON requests.ASIN=tags.ASIN 
WHERE user_id=9 
GROUP BY tag 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: mysql optimizer changes the order in a way it likes better. So practically it doesn't matter what you specify in the original query.

Comment: I have read the doc too, but I've also seen this approach make a *huge* difference, so from my experience, mysql doesn't always do what I claims in the doc

Comment: I did try that previously, and it does appear that mySQL optimises both queries to be the same so this also doesn't use the index. This is why I tried the version with sub-queries - trying to force a 'find the user requests first, then find the tags' approach from mySQL.